# What is wrong with my CSS declaration?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="chapter3.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="blue">
            <p>blue
                <h3>
                    green
                </h3>
            </p>
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's my .html file ^ and below is my CSS (chapter3.css)
I do not understand why my h3 is not displaying as green, I've tried everything I can think of

```
.blue p {
    color: blue;
}

.blue p h3 {
    color: green;
}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because h3 cannot be inside h1.  Only a few elements can be inside a header tag, such as **a**, **em**, **strong**, **code**, **cite**, **span**, **br**, **img**.

If you right click inspect in the browser, you will see that the browser has sorted it out.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="inherit.css">
  </head>
  <body>
     <h1 class="blue">
        <p>blue</p>
     </h1>
     <h3> green </h3>
     <p></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Reference](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiegsyW4cr8AhVHxzgGHa-JC9AQFnoECAkQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F19779519%2Fis-it-valid-to-have-paragraph-elements-inside-of-a-heading-tag-in-html5-p-insid%23%3A%7E%3Atext%3DIn%2520other%2520words%2520you%2520can%2Celement%2520h1%2520in%2520this%2520context.&usg=AOvVaw0qv2WXzflLawYKwUkdZn__)

[Full Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#phrasing-content)

Comment: People, I am rejecting edits to this because this is what came from the browser window.  It is a quote. It is not my layout !!!!